# Log-likelihood of skew-t distribution

Tags: garch, matlab, estimation, distribution

I am trying to estimate **GARCH models** with the use of Hansen's (1994) skew-t distribution. I am using matlab's **ARMAX-GARCH-K toolbox**, where the **log-likelihood** is calculated as:

```
 lamda = parameters(end-1);
 nu = parameters(end);
 c = gamma((nu+1)/2)/(sqrt(pi*(nu-2))*gamma(nu/2));
 a = 4*lamda*c*((nu-2)/(nu-1));
 b = 1 + 3*lamda^2 - a^2;
 indicator1 = ((data(t)-mu(t))./sqrt(h(t))<-a./b);
 indicator2 = ((data(t)-mu(t))./sqrt(h(t))>=-a./b);
 likelihoods1 = log(b) + log(c) - ((nu+1)./2).*log(1+1./(nu-2).*((b.*indicator1.*((data(t)-mu(t))./sqrt(h(t)))+a)./(1-lamda)).^2);
 likelihoods2 = log(b) + log(c) - ((nu+1)./2).*log(1+1./(nu-2).*((b.*indicator2.*((data(t)-mu(t))./sqrt(h(t)))+a)./(1+lamda)).^2); 
 likelihoods = - 0.5*log(h(t)) + indicator1.*likelihoods1 + indicator2.*likelihoods2;
```

where `data(t)` stands for returns, `mu(t)` is the mean from the GARCH model, `h(t)` is the variance from the GARCH model and `parameters` are the parameters of the GARCH model. The whole function for calculating the log-likelihood can be found here (viewing without opening matlab): https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32882-armax-garch-k-toolbox--estimation--forecasting--simulation-and-value-at-risk-applications-/content/garchlik.m

And the distribution is defined as in the following paper on page 6: http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/papers/ier_94.pdf

I have two questions:
1. The square by the b parameter seems to be missing, so after defining b i should take values equal to sqrt(b). Is that right?
2.Where does the term `- 0.5*log(h(t))` in `likelihoods` come from? As it does not appear in the pdf function of the skew-t distribution.

I would be grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- It seems to me there is a problem in the original code the variable b should be defined as   `b= sqrt(1 + 3*lamda^2 - a^2)`

2- The likelihood is defined just after equation 8. in the paper. You have to take into account the $ \frac{1}{\sigma}$ term  (in $ \frac{1}{\sigma} \times g(..)  $ , ie to scale the densitie) . So the `- 0.5*log(h(t))` refers to this part.

Explanation :

Likelihood:

$=   \frac{1}{\sigma} \times g(..) $

Log-Likelihood :

$  = log(\frac{1}{\sigma})+log(   g(..)) $

$ =  log(1)-log(\sigma) +log(   g(..)) $

$ = 0 - log( \sqrt{ \sigma^{2}}) +log(   g(..))$

$ =  - log\left(  (\sigma^{2})^{0.5}\right) +log(   g(..))$

$= -0.5 \times  log(\sigma^{2}) +log(   g(..))$

The first terms of the precedent equation refer to the `- 0.5*log(h(t))` part.

Comment: Thanks for you clarification @Malick, it was really helpful. Just to be sure, this scaling of the densite is true for other distributions as well, right?

Comment: yes if you normalize the y variable (equation 7)